# Why my button is shown and than quickly hidden onResume

Tags: android, android-layout, google-api, google-play-games

It's probably just a silly mistake but I cannot fix it. I have a Google+ sign in a button, which is shown when the user is not logged in. I also have a sign out button, which is GONE when the user is logged in.Everything works except that when I go back to the activity (onResume) I can see the red Google+ button for about a second and than it gets hidden and the sign out button appears. How can I remove this one second during which I can still see the Google+ button ?

This is my layout:
[image]

XML code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/startGameView"
    android:src="@drawable/play"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/startGameView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp">
    <!-- show achievements -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_achievements"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Achievements"/>

    <!-- show leaderboards -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_leaderboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Leaderboard"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code in the activity:

```
public class StartActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
private ImageView mPlay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    mPlay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.startGameView);
    mPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //play animations
            YoYo.with(Techniques.Pulse)
                    .duration(200)
                    .playOn(findViewById(R.id.startGameView));
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.show_achievements).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.show_leaderboard).setOnClickListener(this);
    //mSignOutButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_start, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
        beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    }else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
        signOut();
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else if (view.getId() == R.id.show_achievements){
        Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this,"achivements",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()), 1);
    }else if(view.getId() == R.id.show_leaderboard){
        Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this,"leaderboard",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
                getApiClient(), getString(R.string.number_of_solved_math_problems_leaderboard)), 2);
    }
}
```

BaseActivity code:

```
public abstract class BaseGameActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GameHelper.GameHelperListener {

// The game helper object. This class is mainly a wrapper around this object.
protected GameHelper mHelper;

// We expose these constants here because we don't want users of this class
// to have to know about GameHelper at all.
public static final int CLIENT_GAMES = GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES;
public static final int CLIENT_APPSTATE = GameHelper.CLIENT_APPSTATE;
public static final int CLIENT_PLUS = GameHelper.CLIENT_PLUS;
public static final int CLIENT_ALL = GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL;

// Requested clients. By default, that's just the games client.
protected int mRequestedClients = CLIENT_GAMES;

private final static String TAG = "BaseGameActivity";
protected boolean mDebugLog = false;

/** Constructs a BaseGameActivity with default client (GamesClient). */
protected BaseGameActivity() {
    super();
}

/**
 * Constructs a BaseGameActivity with the requested clients.
 * @param requestedClients The requested clients (a combination of CLIENT_GAMES,
 *         CLIENT_PLUS and CLIENT_APPSTATE).
 */
protected BaseGameActivity(int requestedClients) {
    super();
    setRequestedClients(requestedClients);
}

/**
 * Sets the requested clients. The preferred way to set the requested clients is
 * via the constructor, but this method is available if for some reason your code
 * cannot do this in the constructor. This must be called before onCreate or getGameHelper()
 * in order to have any effect. If called after onCreate()/getGameHelper(), this method
 * is a no-op.
 *
 * @param requestedClients A combination of the flags CLIENT_GAMES, CLIENT_PLUS
 *         and CLIENT_APPSTATE, or CLIENT_ALL to request all available clients.
 */
protected void setRequestedClients(int requestedClients) {
    mRequestedClients = requestedClients;
}

public GameHelper getGameHelper() {
    if (mHelper == null) {
        mHelper = new GameHelper(this, mRequestedClients);
        mHelper.enableDebugLog(mDebugLog);
    }
    return mHelper;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    if (mHelper == null) {
        getGameHelper();
    }
    mHelper.setup(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mHelper.onStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mHelper.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    mHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
}

protected GoogleApiClient getApiClient() {
    return mHelper.getApiClient();
}

protected boolean isSignedIn() {
    return mHelper.isSignedIn();
}

protected void beginUserInitiatedSignIn() {
    mHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
}

protected void signOut() {
    mHelper.signOut();
}

protected void showAlert(String message) {
    mHelper.makeSimpleDialog(message).show();
}

protected void showAlert(String title, String message) {
    mHelper.makeSimpleDialog(title, message).show();
}

protected void enableDebugLog(boolean enabled) {
    mDebugLog = true;
    if (mHelper != null) {
        mHelper.enableDebugLog(enabled);
    }
}

@Deprecated
protected void enableDebugLog(boolean enabled, String tag) {
    Log.w(TAG, "BaseGameActivity.enabledDebugLog(bool,String) is " +
            "deprecated. Use enableDebugLog(boolean)");
    enableDebugLog(enabled);
}

protected String getInvitationId() {
    return mHelper.getInvitationId();
}

protected void reconnectClient() {
    mHelper.reconnectClient();
}

protected boolean hasSignInError() {
    return mHelper.hasSignInError();
}

protected GameHelper.SignInFailureReason getSignInError() {
    return mHelper.getSignInError();
}
```

Comment: could you add your BaseGameActivity code?

Comment: I did added the code for BaseActivity. If you are looking for overriding the onResume method, this activity is not doing it. I checked already :/

Comment: Keep the buttons hidden by default in the layout. In onResume, you just toggle the visibility. The experience shall improve that way.

Comment: @sushantkunal thanks that worked out great! I added this:
 
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            //findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
If you want add your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, @sushantkunal I just tested it a little more, and found out that it does not work.... The effect is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cloned (or refreshed) the samples recently, you'll notice that GameHelper and BaseGameActivity are not longer used. There is an informative video about this change: [Game On! - The death of BaseGameActivity](http://youtu.be/1oSoaFLuTwM).  If you just implement the interfaces to get the callbacks for the state: `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and  `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` your problem should go away.

More specific details on how to use these interfaces is at https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was unaware that these two classes have been deprecated. I will try this approach :)

Answer (score 1):

As I see in [GameHelper class](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java), it disconnects from googleApiClient on `onStop()` and connect on `onStart()`. This is causing of blinking buttons.

If you don't want to change `GameHelper` implementation, make some UI improvement to make it less annoying.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I already applied  what @sushant suggested and it works perfectly.